# DataTemplate is not generating ListItemBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I want to generate ListItemBox using DataTemplate but items are not generating. Please guide me where is the mistake. I have following code in MainWindow.xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="Offline_Website_Downloader.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:bd="clr-namespace:Offline_Website_Downloader"
    Title="Offline Website Downloader" Background="#f5f6f7" Height="500" Width="800"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.Resources>

    <bd:BindingController x:Key="BindingControllerKey"  />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DownloadedWebsitesListBox">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">

                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Width="480">
                            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://google.com">
                                <Label Content="{Binding Path=WebsiteTitle}" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Width="132" TextAlignment="right">
                            <TextBlock Text="Remaining Time: "/>
                            <TextBlock Name="TimeRemaining" Text="js"/>
                </TextBlock>

                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ProgressBar Name="progress1" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Value="30" Background="#FFF" Width="612" Height="10" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="450">Status: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Status}"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Width="162" TextAlignment="right">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Downloading Speed: "/>
                                    <TextBlock Name="DownloadingSpeed" Text="{Binding Path=DownloadingSpeed}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
<ListBox Width="Auto" 
                 Name="WebsiteList"
                 Grid.Column="1" 
                 Grid.Row="2" 
                 Grid.RowSpan="2"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DownloadedWebsitesListBox}"
                 Margin="0,0,0,0">
</ListBox>
</Grid>
</window>
```

and MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    BindingController bc = new BindingController();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

           bc.DownloadingSpeed = "40kb/s";
            bc.WebsiteTitle = "WebsiteTitle";
            bc.Status = "Downloading";
            DataContext = bc;
}
```

and BindingController.cs

```
   public class BindingController
   {
    public BindingController()
    {

    }

    private string _WebsiteTitle;
    public string WebsiteTitle
    {
        set { _WebsiteTitle = value; }
        get { return _WebsiteTitle; }
    }

    private string _Status;
    public string Status
    {
        set { _Status = value ; }
        get { return _Status ; }
    }

    private string _DownloadStartDate;
    public string DownloadStartDate
    {
        set { _DownloadStartDate = value; }
        get { return _DownloadStartDate ; }
    }

    private string _DownloadingSpeed = "0 kb/s";
    public string DownloadingSpeed
    {
        set { _DownloadingSpeed = value; }
        get { return _DownloadingSpeed; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're binding a `ListBox` to an object that contains several properties, but really only represents a single object/state.  The `ListBox` expects to display a list of items (i.e. `IList`, `IBindingList`, `IEnumerable`, `ObservableCollection`).

Assuming you want to display more than one download at a time, which I'm assuming given that you're using a `ListBox`, I would refactor the download properties into a separate class.  You will also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your properties so that when the values are changed, they will be shown in the UI.

```
public class Download : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _WebsiteTitle;
    public string WebsiteTitle
    {            
        get { return _WebsiteTitle; }
        set
        {
            if (_WebsiteTitle == value)
                return;

            _WebsiteTitle = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("WebsiteTitle");
        }
    }

    private string _Status;
    public string Status
    {
        get { return _Status; }
        set
        {
            if (_Status == value)
                return;

            _Status = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }

    private string _DownloadStartDate;
    public string DownloadStartDate
    {
        get { return _DownloadStartDate; }
        set
        {
            if (_DownloadStartDate == value)
                return;

            _DownloadStartDate = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("DownloadStartDate");
        }
    }

    private string _DownloadingSpeed = "0 kb/s";
    public string DownloadingSpeed
    {
        get { return _DownloadingSpeed; }
        set
        {
            if (_DownloadingSpeed == value)
                return;

            _DownloadingSpeed = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("DownloadingSpeed");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The new `BindingController`:

```
public class BindingController
{
    public BindingController()
    {
        this.Downloads = new ObservableCollection<Download>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Download> Downloads { get; private set; }
}
```

Setting up the bindings in XAML:

```
<ListBox Width="Auto" 
         Name="WebsiteList"
         Grid.Column="1" 
         Grid.Row="2" 
         Grid.RowSpan="2"             
         ItemsSource="{Binding Downloads}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DownloadedWebsitesListBox}"
         Margin="0,0,0,0">
</ListBox>
```

Initializing the collection in `MainWindow`

```
Download download = new Download();
download.DownloadingSpeed = "40kb/s";
download.WebsiteTitle = "WebsiteTitle";
download.Status = "Downloading";
bc.Downloads.Add(download);

this.DataContext = bc;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Best answer. I have learn alot. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I have used your code. This is replacing the content of previously created ListItemBox with new content. Please tell me how do i solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean that it's changing all ListBoxes in your application, not just the one you're trying to apply this to?  If so, are you using an unkeyed `Style` somewhere that could be applying itself to all ListBoxItems?  @Zohaib